# How to fix Springboot application.properties error

Tags: java, spring-boot

Cannot work with application.properties in eclipse.
Got an error: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider**.
Have added followed dependencies, but still the same.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what is the value of `javax.inject.version`. Also where there any errors when you build using `mvn clean install` for example?

Comment: java inject version is 1

Comment: Are you running the app via the CLI or in Eclipse? If you are running it via Eclipse, I would suggest that you try the CLI first. It could well be an issue with Eclipse not updating the classpath to reflect the new library addition.

Comment: Yes, running via eclipse, will try in CLI, thanks.